# searching multiple items with Python re

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract hours, mins, seconds and mseconds from a txt file, that may or may not be present in a line. The format is "hh:mm:ss.ms". I know I should so something like this

```
int(re.search('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)', current_line).group(1))
```

but I don't know how to returns these four values to four different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you insist on doing it in one line:

```
hrs, min, sec, msec = (int(group) for group in re.search('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)', current_line).groups())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`groups`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups) on the match object to get a tuple of groups, like this:

```
match = re.search('(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)', current_line)
hour,minute,second,ms = map(int, match.groups())
```